# Do quotas lead to lower overall value assuming input types are equally distributed

Tags: combinatorics

If a country establishes quotas for either males or females in boards of large companies, assuming men and women have the same quality distribution, will the value of all the boards combined be less?

Intuitively it seems that quotas reduce choice and that seems to imply that in certain situations the optimum choice is not available.

Is there proof or disproof of this thesis?

Comment: Unfortunately, a question like this leads to backlash because it goes against the zeitgeist. I have often wondered whether discriminatory hiring practices, especially at the top level positions, open up an arbitrage opportunity for a company's competitors.

Comment: If a pure mathematical question is not askable because it is touching some sensitive point, the enlightenment seems to come to an end :-( But your point is valid. Any restriction on hiring will create a solution that can not exceed the unrestricted solutions, therefore there must be something to arbitrage if you do not have the restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a mathematical question. The assumptions that you need to say such a thing are 'hidden'. If you look for a mathematical "proof" of a sociological problem, you're going to have a bad time. The assumptions under which your assertion is true is that there exists an overall value function such $v: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ where $S$ is the set of all combinations of employees. Then indeed, since $S$ can be assumed to be finite, $\max_{x \in S}(v(x)) \geq \max_{x \in B}(v(x))$ where $B \subset S$ is the subset of combinations with equal gender distribution. However, such a function assumes that all combinations can be chosen immediately, while in practice, employers aren't easily swapped in and out. Hence, it is much more useful to look at a hiring strategy that ensures that $v(\{\text{current employees}\})$ is always reasonably high. One sociological argument is that having a balanced staff seems to generally increase the productivity of the staff - hence this argument is not bad in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just not sure why you needed to add the sociological advice? You did help me a lot to model this though!